# routing prefix pointing to different directory

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new in CakePHP and I have run into an issue with the rounter. Is in possible to point prefix into a different directory that the prefixed route?

My route is:

```
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
    $routes->resources('Users');
});
```

And I would like to use insetad of just `/api/` for example `/api/1.0/`, while maintaining the folder structire.

I am running CakePHP 3.1.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->prefix('1.0', function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/:controller');
    });
});
```